# Merge sort doubly linked list

Tags: algorithm

Linked List pseudocode can be found in CLRS introduction to the algorithms 
but if you want it very much i can rewrite it as demo of the linked list

```
//node structure
 struct node
 {
    int key;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;        
 };
 typedef struct node node;

void split(node *head,node **front,node **back)
{
    node *slow,*fast;

    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
    {
        (*front) = head;
        (*back) = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        slow = head;
        fast = head->next;
        while(fast != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next;
            if(fast != NULL)
            {
                slow = slow->next;
                fast = fast->next;
            }
        }
        (*front) = head;
        (*back) = slow->next;
        slow->next = NULL;
    }
}

void merge(node **head,node *l1,node *l2)
{
    node *newHead, *curr;

    if(l1 == NULL)
        newHead = l2;
    else if(l2 == NULL)
            newHead = l1;
         else
         {
             if(l2->key < l1->key)
             {
                 newHead = l2;
                 l2 = l2->next;
             }
             else
             {
                newHead = l1;
                l1 = l1->next; 
             }
             curr = newHead;
             while(l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL)
             {
                 if(l2->key < l1->key)
                 {
                     curr->next = l2;
                     l2 = l2->next;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     curr->next = l1;
                     l1 = l1->next;
                 }
                 curr = curr->next;
             }
             if(l1 == NULL)
                curr->next = l2;
            else
                curr->next = l1;
         }
         (*head) = newHead;
}

void mergeSort(node **head)
{
    node *h1 = NULL;
    node *h2 = NULL;

    if((*head) != NULL && (*head)->next != NULL)
    {
        split((*head),&h1,&h2);
        mergeSort(&h1);
        mergeSort(&h2);
        merge(head,h1,h2);
    }
}
```

How to set prev pointers properly ?

I tried to set prev pointer of second head to NULL in split function 
   prev[back] <- NULL

I saw geeks' recursive merge function and tried to set prev pointers like this

prev[next[l2]] <- l2 
prev[l2] <- NULL;

prev[next[l1]] <- l1 
prev[l1] <- NULL;

and this don't set prev pointers properly 
Here i used CLRS style pseudocode

Comment: but these `node` seems as singly linked list. Where did you find the prev?

Comment: I know that for singly linked list this function should work
Prev pointers are in the node structure but they are not set 
List node looks like in CLRS introduction to algorithms
struct node {
void * key 
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
};
typedef struct node node;
For void * you can subsititute your favourite type

Comment: *How to set `prev` pointers properly?* I see two schools of thinking: 1) keep the times a `node` is not properly interlinked to a minimum and reassign `prev` as soon as possible 2) do a minimum of (re-)assignments: as no `prev` is used, assign them in the last merge or even a post-processing pass.

Comment: I thought about your second approach after I had sent this question but I prefer first approach because in my opinion merge sort should set both next and prev pointers Second approach is a little bit easier to write
Could you write something more about your first approach

Answer (score 0):

I think i did it on my own 
I had to append rest of the list node by node because of prev pointers

```
void split(node *head,node **front,node **back)
{
    node *slow, *fast;
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
    {
        (*front) = head;
        (*back) = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        slow = head;
        fast = head->next;
        while(fast != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next;
            if(fast != NULL)
            {
                slow = slow->next;
                fast = fast->next;
            }
        }
        (*front) = head;
        (*back) = slow->next;
        (*back)->prev = NULL;
        slow->next = NULL;
    }
}

void merge(node **head,node *l1,node *l2)
{
    node *newHead,*curr;
    if(l1 == NULL)
        newHead = l2;
    else if(l2 == NULL)
        newHead = l1;
    else
    {
        if(l2->key < l1->key)
        {
            newHead = l2;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        else
        {
            newHead = l1;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }
        newHead->prev = NULL;
        curr = newHead;
        while(l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL)
        {
            if(l2->key < l1->key)
            {
                curr->next = l2;
                l2->prev = curr;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
            else
            {
                curr->next = l1;
                l1->prev = curr;
                l1 = l1->next;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        while(l1 != NULL)
        {
            curr->next = l1;
            l1->prev = curr;
            l1 = l1->next;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        while(l2 != NULL)
        {
            curr->next = l2;
            l2->prev = curr;
            l2 = l2->next;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    (*head) = newHead;
}

void mergeSort(node **head)
{
    node *h1 = NULL;
    node *h2 = NULL;
    if((*head) != NULL && (*head)->next != NULL)
    {
        split((*head),&h1,&h2);
        mergeSort(&h1);
        mergeSort(&h2);
        merge(head,h1,h2);
    }
}
```

Comment: (I'll never understand *why* to think/code a separate `split`.) When one of the lists runs out in `merge()`, just append the other to whatever destination - no link but the `prev` in that tail's head will (need to) change. Once this works, to get 2nd opinions on the code as such, consider posting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - comment your code properly ("no one will" consult external references - what is the *interface* of "your" doubly-linked-list?) & be sure to heed [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you have better solution you can share it with me 
Another divide and conquer approach is partition sort 
Do you remember Turbo Pascal ? It has procedure in examples for sorting arrays The same procedure is in Wirth's book Algorithms+Data Structures = Programs 
If i ask a quesition how to rewrite this procedure to sort also doubly linked lists will you write someting about it

Comment: `[would] you write [something] about [partition sorting doubly linked lists]` depends: if I think a question good, think I can give a useful answer and find time.

Comment: `better solution [for merge-sorting doubly linked lists]` Have each pass *distribute* ordered runs to as many separate lists as you are willing to handle. (Back when, I used two.)

Comment: How to replace swap operation with insert and delete assuming that pointers to the nodes we want swap are given

Comment: `How to replace swap operation with …` you lost me there. Merge-sort doesn't swap, no code in this Q&As does mention it as of 18/6/1. If you want answers about *partition sort*, ask a separate question about it.