# Partition sort for doubly linked list

Tags: algorithm

Code translated to C from Wirth's book is following

```
void quicksort(int *array, int left, int right)
{
    int v=array[(left+right)/2];
    int i,j,x;
    i=left;
    j=right;
    do {
        while (array[i]<v) i++;
        while (array[j]>v) j--;
        if (i<=j) {
            x=array[i];
            array[i]=array[j];
            array[j]=x;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while (i<=j);
    if (j>left) quicksort(array, left, j);
    if (i<right) quicksort(array, i, right);
}
```

but that uses arrays - my stab at doubly linked lists ([node structure here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50508234) ):

```
void partitonSort(node **head,node **tail)
{
    node *v; // here I want to use first or last element as pivot
    node *i,*j;
    do
    {
        while(i->key < v->key) i = i->next;
        while(j->key > v->key) j = j->prev;
        if(/*what boolean expression should I use here*/)
        {
            /*Is it necessary to replace swap operation 
              with insert and delete operations and 
              how to do it */
            i = i->next;
            j = j->prev;
        }
    }
    while(/*what boolean expression should I use here*/);
    if(/*what boolean expression should I use here*/)
           partitonSort(head,&j);
    if(/*what boolean expression should I use here*/)
           partitonSort(&i,tail);      
}
```

I left questions in the code comments:
- Should I replace swap operation with insert and delete
 and how to do this
- What boolean expressions I should use

Answer (score 1):

Here is my concise solution with detailed comments:

```
/* a node of the doubly linked list */
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};

/* A utility function to swap two elements */
void swap ( int* a, int* b )
{   int t = *a;      *a = *b;       *b = t;   }

// A utility function to find last node of linked list
struct Node *lastNode(Node *root)
{
    while (root && root->next)
        root = root->next;
    return root;
}

/* Considers last element as pivot, places the pivot element at its
   correct position in sorted array, and places all smaller (smaller than
   pivot) to left of pivot and all greater elements to right of pivot */
Node* partition(Node *l, Node *h)
{
    // set pivot as h element
    int x  = h->data;

    // similar to i = l-1 for array implementation
    Node *i = l->prev;

    // Similar to "for (int j = l; j <= h- 1; j++)"
    for (Node *j = l; j != h; j = j->next)
    {
        if (j->data <= x)
        {
            // Similar to i++ for array
            i = (i == NULL)? l : i->next;

            swap(&(i->data), &(j->data));
        }
    }
    i = (i == NULL)? l : i->next; // Similar to i++
    swap(&(i->data), &(h->data));
    return i;
}

/* A recursive implementation of quicksort for linked list */
void _quickSort(struct Node* l, struct Node *h)
{
    if (h != NULL && l != h && l != h->next)
    {
        struct Node *p = partition(l, h);
        _quickSort(l, p->prev);
        _quickSort(p->next, h);
    }
}

// The main function to sort a linked list. It mainly calls _quickSort()
void quickSort(struct Node *head)
{
    // Find last node
    struct Node *h = lastNode(head);

    // Call the recursive QuickSort
    _quickSort(head, h);
}
```

Comment: I like the code comments. Pity returning more than one result from a procedure doesn't come natural with C - how to elegantly [limit worst case space usage by handling the smaller partition first](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Optimizations)?

Comment: (I missed that the *procedure comment* for `Node* partition(Node *l, Node *h)` inappropriately uses "array lingo".)

Comment: I think that geeks have the same solution but what if it is not allowed to swap data (we can rearrange pointers instead) and we want to use Hoare partition instead of Lomuto Maybe it would be better if we use insert and delete instead of swap Insert and delete operations should not allocate/deallocate memory in that case

Comment: Gonnet and Baeza-Yates have nice solution for singly linked list therefore to get Partition Sort for doubly linked list is enough to set prev pointers correctly but we will get Lomuto partition in that way

Answer (score 0):

Yes but I prefer to change links instead of data

Here is pseudocode

```
PartitionSort(L)
     if head[L] != tail[L] then
//Choose the pivot node, first node or last node is the option
        pivot := tail[L]
//Partition step, we distribute nodes of the linked list into three sublists
        curr := head
        while curr != NULL do
             if key[curr] < key[pivot] then
                    pushBack(curr,Less)
             else if key[curr] = key[pivot] then
                    pushBack(curr,Equal)
             else  
                    pushBack(curr,Greater)
                  end if
             end if
             curr := next[curr]
        end while
   // Here me make sure that we partitioned linked list correctly
   // We should set next of tail pointers and prev of head pointers to NULL 
   //Now we do recursive calls on sublists with keys not equal to the pivot key
       PartitionSort(Less)
       PartitionSort(Greater)
  // Now we concatenate sublists
      if tail[Less] != NULL then
           next[tail[Less]] := head[Equal]
      else
          head[Less] := head[Equal]
      end if
      if head[Equal] then
            prev[head[Equal]]  = tail[Less]
            tail[Less] = tail[Equal]
      end if

      if tail[Less] != NULL then
           next[tail[Less]] := head[Greater]
      else
          head[Less] := head[Greater]
      end if
      if head[Greater] then
            prev[head[Greater]]  = tail[Less]
            tail[Less] = tail[Greater]
      end if
      L := Less
    end if
```